# Is escaping the Accept header necessary?

Tags: java, jersey, security

I have a Jersey app that has been run through our corporations website vulnerability tool.  It came back with a vulnerability that is quite odd.  If you send in this header:

```
"*/*'"!@$^*\/:;.,?{}[]`~-_<sCrIpT>alert(81363)</sCrIpT>"
```

you actually get it back in the response and it is not escaped. Anyone think this is a problem?

Here is the actual response:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
Accept: */*'"!@$^*\/:;.,?{}[]`~-_<sCrIpT>alert(81363)</sCrIpT>
Pragma: no-cache
...
```

And one more thing.  I just upgraded to jersey 1.14 and it still does this...

Comment: This may get you started http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header_injection

Comment: And this https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Response_Splitting

Answer (score 0):

You mean in produced error message? Something like:

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2012 14:30:30 GMT
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Closing connection #0
The HTTP header field "Accept" with value "..." could not be parsed
```

?

If so, we can definitely do something about it, please report this as a new RFE at http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY. (I wasn't able to reproduce anything else related to this issue).

Thanks!

Comment: No.  From what I can detect, when you have an Accept header that does not match one that you have set up, it returns a 404 (or whatever) correctly.  The problem is that Jersey sends back the same header that it received.  So Jersey apparently does not escape the header before parsing it, which is a bad deal.  Also, our tools flag anything that sends back illegal characters in a response because they are obviously unescaped ie.  not dealt with correctly.  I do think this is a Jersey bug...

Comment: can you share reproducible testcase?

Comment: or maybe upgrade to latest Jersey version? All I'm getting when I use non standard Accept header is "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" with text/plain as content type.

Comment: Just looking and all my services are ok except for the one that does this:  public JAXBElement<List> searchV1(@Context UriInfo ui, @PathParam("dealerCode") String dealerCode...

Comment: does what? method signature is incomplete.

Comment: Sorry, Pavel.  My app has about 15 services.  The only one that returns the incorrect header is one where I return a JAXBElement.  I also grab the UriInfo object as well. Maybe that is the cause?  The rest of the method is just normal stuff.  Maybe we should take this offline?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I've got the same issue that webscan is complaining about.